# Graceful degradation of HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, html

I am using native HTML5 History API calls and I am aware of the [cross brower compatibility issues](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API), but in my specific use case, those doesn't matter. For my limited needs, the browsers are behaving consistently & the table in the above link tells the same story. So I don't really want to add another JS library on the page (History.js) but I definitely want it to fail gracefully in browsers which don't support them. I don't want them to throw JS errors.

For instance, IE (and I imagine other non-supporting browsers would too) throws this JS error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceState'`

I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
window.history = window.history || {};
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(window.history)) {
    window.history.prototype.replaceState = function(a,b,c) {};
    window.history.prototype.pushState = function(a,b,c) {};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `pushState` exists in the history object.

```
if( !(window.history && 'pushState' in window.history) )
```

Comment: Was just testing it once, thanks! Accepted & upvoted :) BTW, I edited the answer to a better version of example.